# Find if there is a line on table : count or first?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, query-optimization, ruby-on-rails-2

I wish to do some optimizations on my SQL queries.
Without doing a performance test for it, what query is the most time-consuming ? I am almost sure they return the same result.

- `!MyClass.find(:first, :conditions => c).nil?`
- `MyClass.count(:conditions => c) > 0`
- `MyClass.count(:conditions => c, :limit => 1) > 0`

Regards

Comment: Why don't you do each one yourself and see how long it takes?

Comment: You can use .exists? I suppose it is the cheapest one. It returns "SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE ..."

Answer (score 0):

You can test it for your own. Writing a performance test with less then 15 lines of code. For more information:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html

Answer (score 0):

I ask the question because I thought the answer was an evidence. It appears not.

So I do some average time for several queries. Here is the result, ordered by time :

```
.count(:conditions => c, :limit => 1) > 0;
=> 0.042037

.count(:conditions => c) > 0
=> 0.037781

.count(:select => '1', :conditions => c) > 0
=> 0.035976

.count(:select => '1', :conditions => c, :limit => 1) > 0
=> 0.034157

.find(:first, :conditions => c).nil?
=> 0.000377

.find(:first, :select => '1', :conditions => c).nil?
( equivalent to .exists?(c) )
=> 0.000184
```

The last one is the most efficient. Thanks for the tip of `:select => '1'` !